# the max number of icloud accounts you can set up on iphone 5

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I recently had my iPhone stolen, it was recovered but both of my apple ids were altered and I can not use them.  the person who stole the phone must have set up one or more accounts because when setting up new account it error messaged maximum number of free accounts activated.  What is the maximum number of free accounts on iPhone 5?

I have new phone and would like to know the maximum allowed..

Comment: This seems more about asking Why apple did this than what do I do next given Apple does this. Let’s see if it needs more answers if it gets edited to narrow down which possible question is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have tried a bit harder to get my original IDs back - as everything you bought with them is currently in the hands of someone else.

[Contact Apple.](https://www.apple.com/support/contact/)

The answer to your question is 3, but that's not the point. Apple can override that if you can persuade them.